# PHP serial port reading, doesn't load the site

Tags: php, apache, port, virtual

So I want to read virtual serial port with PHP. I can write to the serial port without problem but when i try to read the page doesn't load.

I've tried fread, fgets. I also send new line (.PHP_EOL) but nothing works.

```
$fp = fopen("/dev/pts/3","w+");
$fp2 = fopen("/dev/pts/2","w+");

if(!$fp || $fp2){
echo "Error!";
die();
}

else{

fwrite($fp, "works".PHP_EOL);
fwrite($fp2, "works too".PHP_EOL);
$data = fgets($fp);
echo $data;

fclose($fp);
fclose($fp2);
}
```

I would like to get back my text, but the webpage doesn't load at all. If I remove the "fgets" part it works fine.

Comment: Nothing in logs?

Comment: can you try it with length limit in fgets - fe fgets($fp, 1024)

Comment: @AndreaManzi Nothing. I think the page should load first to get anything in the log file. It seems the problem is something like endless reading.

Comment: @myxaxa Same result. Endless loading.

Comment: @T.Tamas for debug, add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at top of code

Comment: @AndreaManzi Added, but still nothing. Maybe I'm not doing it the right way.

Comment: @T.Tamas have you tried fread($fp, 128)?

Comment: @AndreaManzi Just tried and nothing. Can it be a virtual port problem? I've used socat to simulate serial ports. After creating I gave read and write permissions.

Comment: have you tried fopen with second parameter r (read) `$fp = fopen("/dev/pts/3","r");` ?